# найти ошибку с sql на hql

Tags: sql, sql-server, intellij-idea, hibernate, hql

с этого

```
SELECT TOP 1 Persons.LastName,Persons.FirstName,Products.ProductType,Orders.SumOfOrder 
    FROM Persons
    INNER JOIN  Orders
            ON Orders.PersonID = Persons.PersonID
    INNER JOIN Products
            ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductID

    ORDER BY Orders.SumOfOrder DESC;
```

На это, но выдает ошибку подскажите пожалуйста)

```
 List<Object[]> result =
                session.createQuery(
                        "select firstName, lastName, sumOfOrder" +
                        "from Orders o join o.Persons" +
                        "from o join o.Products" + "order by o.sumOfOrder desc")
                         .setMaxResults(1).list();
    }
```

Мне нужно вывести результат как имя и фамилия персоны.

Comment: Вероятно, пробелов не хватает при конкатенации строки запроса.

Comment: *выдает ошибку* - вообще-то сообщения об ошибках принято цитировать, обычно их достаточно, чтобы понять, где грабли. А по сути проблемы согласен с предыдущим оратором.

Comment: А зачем `List<Object[]>`, если там `SELECT TOP 1`?

Answer (score 0):

А что делают два from в hql?
Я бы написал как-то так

"select p.firstName, p.lastName, o.sumOfOrder " +

"from Orders o join o.Persons p " +

"join p.Products pr " + "order by o.sumOfOrder desc"